# I want to avoid duplicate dates in google sheets by using a script

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I just signed up and need help with a problem, I am new to the google app scripts and I am struggling to create a script to avoid duplicate date.

The sheet will capture data once a day and to avoid duplicate dates I am trying to write a script.

I have looked at different methods, tried arrays and that also wont seem to work.

I created a small test site to explain here with the current issue I am facing.

Below is the code when the user clicks a save button, please not I am only struggling with the if statement. I get all the dates but I am unable to break it into separate dates in order to do the if statement.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Code should be added as text, not as image.

Comment: Thank you Rubin, do you mind telling me why my array only return 5 values from a list of dates?

Comment: Please add the code as text. Also add more details to be able to reproduce the problem.  Ref. [mcve]

Comment: var values = ss.getSheetByName("DataBase1").getRange(3,2,ss.getLastRow(),1).getValues();      this line only gives 5 values and not 10 or 20 values

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add the code as text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code the variable values is indeed an array retrieved from your sheet using getValues()

You can manipulate that array as you loop through it removing the duplicate based on your variable names date or load into a separate array

```
var i = 0;
var lenValues = values.length;
var newArray = [];
for (i = 0; i < lenValues; i++) {
  if (date !== values[i]) {
     newArray.push(values[i]);
  }
}
```

Now, dates can be tricky, I would use the debugger and set a breakpoint to inspect the data format stored in the values variable and adjust accordingly.

Once you have the new array, you may decide to write those values to another sheet

```
writeDataToSheet(newArray, "Target sheet name");

// Writes a 2D array of data to sheet
function writeDataToSheet(data, sheetName) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  goToSheet(sheetName, ss);
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A");
  range.clear();
  // write date to active sheet starting at the 2nd row
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
  return sheet.getName();
}

function goToSheet(sheetName, ss) {
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(sheetName));
}
```

Now, if all you want to do is alert the user the data already exists try this instead:

```
var i = 0;
var found = false;
var lenValues = values.length;
for (i = 0; i < lenValues; i++) {
  if (date == values[i]) {
     found = true;
     break;
  }
}
```

Put this before your if statement and change to:

```
if (found) {
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I have to ask, the loop you suggested, will this be put before my current if statement? How does this prevent the duplicate entry?

Comment: I modified my answer for you

Comment: Thank you for responding, I did as you suggested. It is still allowing duplicates. As in my code it says 'Yes' date available. However it say 'Yes' even if the date exists. I understand that when the date is found the loop should break. I don't know what I am missing, how do I upload pictures to the comments to show you what I am getting.

Comment: Remember what I said in my answer, dates are tricky. Set a breakpoint and examine both the date and values variables. You need to compare apples to apples. Also, the formatting toolbar has a icon for inserting images, but it is best to list the code inline using the code formatting.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, your information and guidance on this subject was very useful.

Comment: This answer is working perfectly, however I noticed it only matches the first 5 dates in my sheet, the rest it will duplicate. What can be the reason for this?

Comment: If you set sharing to view only on your sheet and post the URL I will be glad to have a look.

Answer (score -1):

This code will work to remove duplicates. My original dates are in C9:C16
The problem here is that it has converted the dates into strings, you may need to convert back to dates.

```
function removeDuplicate(){
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();

   let originalDates = sheet.getRange('C9:C16').getDisplayValues().flat();
   console.log(originalDates);

   let datesNoDup = originalDates.filter((date,i) => originalDates.indexOf(date) == i);
   console.log(datesNoDup);

 }
```

````
7:14:26 AM  Notice  Execution started

7:14:27 AM  Info    [ '2/1/2011',
                      '2/1/2011',
                      '2/25/2011',
                      '3/17/2011',
                      '7/25/2011',
                      '10/19/2011',
                      '3/17/2011',
                      '7/25/2011' ]

7:14:27 AM  Info    [ '2/1/2011', 
                      '2/25/2011', 
                      '3/17/2011', 
                      '7/25/2011', 
                      '10/19/2011' ]

7:14:27 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```
````

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, as I mentioned in my comment above also now, I noticed my array only matches the first 5 dates in my sheet, the rest it will duplicate. What can be the reason for this?